# Comparing certain contents of a string in C

Tags: c, string, c-strings

So, I have an issue. I'm trying to only get the inside of a string as given by this example:

User input: insert("someWord")
And I want to first make sure that the user spelt insert(" correctly, then I want to copy the string contained inside the " ". As of now, I have a function with a parameter that is the full user input, and inside that function, I have the following:

```
method header(char *string){
  char insert[]="insert(";
  if((strncmp(string,insert,6)==0)
   {
     //the first part was right up to the "
     //how do I now get the string contained between " "?
   }
  else
   {  //invalid input
   }
}
```

I'm not even 100% positive the strncmp method is comparing the first 6 letters of the two strings correctly.

Comment: "I'm not even 100% positive the strncmp method is comparing the first 6 letters of the two strings correctly." Why not? Doesn't testing your code or reading the [strcmp man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strncmp) give you that info? As for extracting the sub-string, just go through the rest of the [standard string functions](http://linux.die.net/man/3/string) to see which ones can help you. For example, you could use `strtok` with `"` as the delimiter or `strchr` to find where the inner string starts and ends.

Comment: Also `"insert("` is 7 characters not 6. Better to use `strlen(insert)` rather than a hard coded number. And it also doesn't include the `"` character after the `(` which you seem to also want to match.

Answer (score 3):

[`sscanf(3)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html) to the rescue:

```
char insert[31];
int matched = sscanf(string, "insert(\"%[^\"]30s\")", insert);
if (matched) printf("Got %s\n", insert);
```

This matches a string no larger than 30 characters that doesn't contain a `"` and is surrounded by `insert("` and `")`.

Comment: You may want to make the buffer 1 byte bigger as the scanf will add a null termination after a 30 byte string, requiring 31 bytes of storage.....

Answer (score 0):

`strncmp` will compare the exact number of characters or terminate when it see the first null.

So,

```
strncmp("inser","insert(",6)     // false -- the first string too short
strncmp("insert","insert(",6)    // true, the first 6 char match
strncmp("insert(","insert(",6)   // true, first 6 char match
strncmp("insertxyz","insert(",6) // true, the first 6 chars match
strncmp("insert","inse",6)       // false -- the second string too short
strncmp("append","insert",6)     // false -- they just don't match
```

**Note** that "insert(" is actually **7** characters long (8 if you include the null byte), so comparing with `strncmp(,,6)` will **not** take the training '(' into account -- not sure if that is your problem.

In your case there is no real reason to use `strncmp` -- just use `strcmp` instead (or the sscanf solution suggested by a3f)

Answer (score 0):

`strchr`, `strncpy` and simple pointer arithmetic can also do the trick, e.g.

```
method header(char *string){
    char insert[]="insert(";
    if (strncmp (string, insert, 6) == 0) {
        char text[MAXC] = "", *p = string + 7, *ep = NULL;
        if ((ep = strchr (p, ')')) && ep - p < MAXC)
            strncpy (text, p, ep - p);
        printf ("header text: '%s'\n", text);
    }
    else {  //invalid input
    }
}
```

A short example that prints the wanted text between the parenthesis (text cannot contain an embedded close parenthesis).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXC 128

void header (char *string);

int main (void) {

    char string[] = "insert(headerinfo)";

    header (string);

    return 0;
}

void header (char *string)
{
    char insert[] = "insert(";
    if (strncmp (string, insert, 6) == 0) {
        char text[MAXC] = "", *p = string + 7, *ep = NULL;
        if ((ep = strchr (p, ')')) && ep - p < MAXC)
            strncpy (text, p, ep - p);
        printf ("header text: '%s'\n", text);
    }
    else {  //invalid input
    }
}
```

**note:** the *nul-terminating* byte is provided by virtue of initialization. If `text` is reused with `strncpy` within the same scope, you should affirmatively *nul-terminate* `text` for each subsequent use.

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/headertxt
header text: 'headerinfo'
```